# Test if first element in a map traversal?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to test to see how many times you've already looped over the map?

Something like the following:

```
@item.itemImgs.map { img =>
    @if(img._1) {
        <html stuff>
    }
}
```

The above is the Play Framework templating engine in a `*.scala.html` document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zipWithIndex` and get the element index, with that you know how many times you have mapped the collection, note that it's zero index based:

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4).zipWithIndex.map { case (e,i) => println(i + ": " + e ) }
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
```